# If $f$ is continuous at $a$, is it continuous in some open interval around $a$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a$, is it continuous in some open interval around $a$?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but the answer is a consequence of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/170231/55235).

Comment: There you go! $5$ answers in less than a minute!

Answer (score 25):

No, that's not true. Take the function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x) = x$ if $x \not\in \mathbb Q$. Then $f$ is discontinuous everywhere except at $0$ (can you prove this?).

Comment: This is fascinating and basically stretches the concept of continuity, or at least illustrates a facet of it. The question suggests itself, if $f$ is continuous only at zero, to where does it continue? ;)

Comment: This works whenever $x$ and $0$ are replaced by two functions that converge to the same value at certain points, right? For instance, with $x^2$ and $x$ the associated function would be continuous only at $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @JackM: Yes, it works.

Comment: @Kaz what do you mean ?

Answer (score 15):

No. Take $$x\mapsto \left\lfloor\frac 1 x\right\rfloor^{-1}$$

It is continuous at $x=0$; but has discontinuities on every $x_n=\dfrac 1 n$

**ADD** On a side note, it is not hard to show this function is continuous at $0$. Use the squeeze theorem with $x$ and $2x$ for $x\to 0^+$ and $x$ and $x/2$ for $x\to 0^{-}$. Of course, we need to set $0\mapsto 0$.

Answer (score 13):

No. Consider the function 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x &\text{if } x\in \mathbb Q\\
-x &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
which is continuous at $0$, but not at any other real number.

Answer (score 12):

Not necessarily:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }x\in\Bbb Q\\
-x&\text{if }x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q
\end{cases}$$

is continuous only at $0$.

Answer (score 10):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) is a function that is continuous at every irrational point, and discontinuous at every rational one.  So the answer is no.

Answer (score 6):

Fix an enumeration of the rationals, $q_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. We define the following function:$$\large f(x)=\sum_{q_n<x}\frac1{2^n}$$

That is, we sum $\frac1{2^n}$ for all the $n$ such that $q_n$ is strictly smaller than $x$. This function is continuous at every irrational number, but discontinuous at every rational number. Therefore it cannot be continuous on any interval.

Comment: For more fun, see the addendum [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367691/find-a-function-f-bbb-r-to-bbb-r-which-is-discontinuous-at-1-frac-12-fra/367715#367715).